# Core Data: UIManagedDocument or AppDelegate to setup core data stack?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data, sdk

I am a little confused about where to setup my Core data Stack. In the Appdelegate or using a shared instance of  UIManagedDocument, described here?: http://adevelopingstory.com/blog/2012/03/core-data-with-a-single-shared-uimanageddocument.html

Right now I have by core data stack setup in my AppDelegate and I am passing my MOC around between the viewcontrollers. But would it be better to migrate to UIManagedDocument and make a shared Instance, so I don't have to pass the MOC around all the time? And also because its newer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`UIManagedDocument` is used to sync data (typically files) to iCloud. It is only tangentially related to Core Data.

Core Data setup is typically done in the `AppDelegate` so there is nothing wrong with what you are doing there. In fact, if you create a new project using Core Data that is how the Xcode template will do it.

You usually do not need to pass your `ManagedObjectContext` around from viewcontroller to viewcontroller. It is better to create a singleton Data Access layer which can provide context anywhere in your app. There are some cases where you might want to have a private MOC for a viewcontroller, but not very often.

Here's some code to create a singleton DataAccessLayer:

DataAccessLayer.h

```
@interface DataAccessLayer : NSObject

   //Saves the Data Model onto the DB
   - (void)saveContext;

   //DataAccessLayer singleton instance shared across application
   + (id) sharedInstance;
   + (void)disposeInstance;
   // Returns the managed object context for the application.
   // If the context doesn't already exist, it is created and bound 
   // to the persistent store coordinator for the application.
   + (NSManagedObjectContext *)context;
@end
```

DataAccessLayer.m

```
#import "DataAccessLayer.h"

//static instance for singleton implementation
static DataAccessLayer __strong *manager = nil;

//Private instance methods/properties
@interface DataAccessLayer ()

// Returns the managed object context for the application.
// If the context doesn't already exist, it is created and 
// bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

// Returns the managed object model for the application.
// If the model doesn't already exist, it is created from the application's model.
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;

// Returns the persistent store coordinator for the application.
// If the coordinator doesn't already exist, it is created and the application's 
// store added to it.
@property (readonly,strong,nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;

// Returns the URL to the application's Documents directory.
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;
@end


@implementation DataAccessLayer

@synthesize managedObjectContext = __managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = __managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = __persistentStoreCoordinator;

//DataAccessLayer singleton instance shared across application
+ (id)sharedInstance
{
    @synchronized(self) 
    {
        if (manager == nil)
            manager = [[self alloc] init];
    }
    return manager;
}

+ (void)disposeInstance
{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        manager = nil;
    }
}

+(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    return [[DataAccessLayer sharedInstance] managedObjectContext];
}

//Saves the Data Model onto the DB
- (void)saveContext
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) 
    {
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) 
        {
            //Need to come up with a better error management here.
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        } 
    }
}

// Returns the managed object context for the application.
// If the context doesn't already exist, it is created and 
// bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    if (__managedObjectContext != nil)
        return __managedObjectContext;

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) 
    {
        __managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [__managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return __managedObjectContext;
}

// Returns the managed object model for the application.
// If the model doesn't already exist, it is created from the 
// application's model.
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (__managedObjectModel != nil) 
        return __managedObjectModel;

    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Model" 
                                               withExtension:@"momd"];
    __managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] 
                         initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return __managedObjectModel;
}

// Returns the persistent store coordinator for the application.
// If the coordinator doesn't already exist, it is created and the 
// application's store added to it.
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (__persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) 
        return __persistentStoreCoordinator;

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] 
                         URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyData.sqlite"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    __persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc]
                                     initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

    if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                           configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) 
    {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }    

    return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

// Returns the URL to the application's Documents directory.
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory
                                         inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}

@end
```

Any time you need context, you can grab it using:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [DataAccessLayer context];
```

This design generally works well. `NSManagedObjectContext` is a very lightweight object, so there isn't a real performance penalty keeping it around. However, if you need to do Core Data stuff on other threads, the design needs to change a bit. From [Apple's docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html):

> You must create the managed context on the thread on which it will be
>   used. If you use NSOperation, note that its init method is invoked on
>   the same thread as the caller. You must not, therefore, create a
>   managed object context for the queue in the queue’s init method,
>   otherwise it is associated with the caller’s thread. Instead, you
>   should create the context in main (for a serial queue) or start (for a
>   concurrent queue).
>
> Using thread confinement, you should not pass managed objects or
>   managed object contexts between threads. To “pass” a managed object
>   from one context another across thread boundaries, you either:
>
> - Pass its object ID (objectID) and use objectWithID: or existingObjectWithID:error: 
>     on the receiving managed object context. The corresponding managed objects must have 
>     been saved—you cannot pass the ID of a newly-inserted managed object to another context.
> - Execute a fetch on the receiving context.

Comment: If I remember right, you do need to worry about cross thread calls though... I think. Meaning that while you can access it from any thread, you can't share a context between threads. [Concurrency with Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html) from Apple might be a useful read.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear and quick answer.. Thank you to you, Joushua too :).... I just thought that creating a singleton with the core data setup, was bad practice.. but it makes "life" a lot easier, all that passing of MOC is "terrible" :D

Comment: Yep, @Joshua has a good point. If you need to do async calls (for things like large data loads) then you need to adjust the design a bit for those calls. It's still very straightforward, but not as straightforward as a singleton. I'll make a note of that in the answer in case anyone is interested.

Comment: I was on the same page all the time and did never use UIManagedDocument - until I watched the latest stanford classes on iTunesU, where they are using UIManagedDocument. My irritation about that lead me to this question here...

Answer (score 1):

The singleton method above is very slick.  A much simpler approach is to treat the appDelegate as a singleton, which it is.  Create the properties in your appDelegate then a version of the following line will retrieve the one you want.  For example to retrieve the moc

```
self.managedObjectContext = [(MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
```