# How to use Core Data without Storyboards?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data

I am trying to use Core Data without storyboarding in my app. I want to manage many relationships and I have a kind of singleton class to manage the access to the managedObjectContext, model, and persistentStoreCordinator I got it from this link [Singleton datalayer without appdelegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14876988/core-data-uimanageddocument-or-appdelegate-to-setup-core-data-stack)

My problem is that I dont want to use StoryBoards but all the examples that I found use Storyboards. I have problems with UITableView because appDelegate doesnot found it.

I want to create a Single Application and then with a singleton to manage the context and everything, show the objects that I get in a JSON format with nsfetchedresultcontroller or with fetchrequests if I only need one item.

I am using this class. also I have another class called CoreDataTableViewController.h/m it is a subclass of UITableViewController and it has the methods of NSFetchedResultControllers. I got this of the Stanford IOS course. Then I have my MainViewController its a subclass of CoreDataTableViewController and there I get the data from the Json and put it in my ManagedObject and also I overwrite the method cellForRowAtIndexPath. But when I start the simulator I have an error. loaded the "ViewController" nib but didn't get a UITableView.

Answer (score 4):

Core Data doesn't care whether you're using Storyboards or not. Just copy the Core Data related code that you need (you can create a singleton containing the relevant managedObjectModel/context, persistentStoreCoordinator objects and methods) and add it to your own project.

Comment: Hi, I am using this class. also I have another class called CoreDataTableViewController.h/m it is a subclass of UITableViewController and it has the methods of NSFetchedResultControllers. I got this of the Stanford IOS course. Then I have my MainViewController its a subclass of CoreDataTableViewController and there I get the data from the Json and put it in my ManagedObject and also I overwrite the method cellForRowAtIndexPath. But when I start the simulator I have an error. 
loaded the "ViewController" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'

Comment: Make sure the `view` outlet in the nib is correctly hooked up to a UITableView.

Comment: Ok sorry, I found out, I had to use the same xcdatamodel.

Comment: Now, the problem is UIView tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]:. I thought that nsfetchedResultController did that. But I guess the problem now is when I get JSON data. But thank you for all

Answer (score 2):

There are no relation between the two.  If you need an example of core data that doesnot use storyboard, try [Apple's](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008305).  Good luck!

Comment: I would like to create it as Single Application without click in Core Data option, and doing everything by code.