# How to manage a big ManagedObjectModel with 6 entities and relationships? Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, afnetworking, uimanageddocument

I would like to know how to manage a big Core Data ManagedObjectModel like this, but with more attributes in every entity. Proyectos(means Projects) and Desarrolladores(means Developers) will be a Table View. The other entities will be only items. I want to manage with singleTon for the fetchedResultController and to control the managedObjectContext [image: Model]

Does anyone knows about some examples like this? Big Models or something? All that I find is with only one entity or two.

Another question is that I am going to get all the data from JSON requests, so I want to know if I had to use NSPersistentStoreCordinator or I should use UIManagedDocument?
This is other example

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: I have used Core Data with a model of more than 20 entities without problems.

Comment: Did you do it without any library? I mean hand made with code by yourself? I think I have problems when I try to use Singleton classes to manage all the entities.

Comment: Yes I did it by myself. I used the singleton only to ensure I have one context for all the App. I have several fetched results controllers, but all of them use the same context. I don't see what you mean with 'Singleton classes to manage all the entities'? I only have one Singleton.

Comment: Sorry, I want one Singleton to manage the context. I already get it from here [link][http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14876988/core-data-uimanageddocument-or-appdelegate-to-setup-core-data-stack]. With Singleton classes I meant that I had this dataaccesslayer singleton and other singleton for fetchedresultcontrollers. Maybe here is my problem.. Do you use something like the DataAccesslayer in the link to manage your context?

Comment: I prefer to use a Singleton for UIManagedDocument instead of DataAccessLayer. I learned this in Stanford CS193p course from iTunesU. My solution is very similar to this one: http://www.adevelopingstory.com/blog/2012/03/core-data-with-a-single-shared-uimanageddocument.html

Comment: Why do you prefer UIManagedDocument instead of DataAccesLayer? I have watched CS193p course but I cant't manage all the entities following their steps..

Comment: Look at my answer and my links. The two advantatges of UIManagedDocument are: 1) it takes care of setting up the Core Data Stack 2) it integrates easily with iCloud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using a sigle shared (Singleton) UIManagedDocument to ensure that you have the same UIManagedObjectContext for all the classes in your App.

Example on how to set this up can be found in thos blog:

http://www.adevelopingstory.com/blog/2012/03/core-data-with-a-single-shared-uimanageddocument.html

You can have several NSFetchedResultsController that will use this shared UIManagedObjectContext (from the shared UIManagedDocument).

This is a sample project I did for the Stanford course CS193p on iPhone programming. It uses Core Data with the sigleton I am proposing.

https://bitbucket.org/jcatalan007/cdspot

Comment: Thank you, I will try to do it again following your project. Do you always create your projects with Storyboars? even with 20 entities?

Comment: Man, storyboard is for the UI, and Entities are for Core Data. What do you mean exactly? And I prefer to use storyboards for every project. In one project I am currently working I am using storyboards + nib files, but stroyboards and autolayout is the way to go IMHO and Apple is pushing hard into this direction.

Comment: @RoxeeMan don't forget to vote up my answer and select it if it solves your problem so this post can be useful to other people. In case you have any other question just ask me.

Comment: So. if I have many tableViews, do I only have to create different classes like CoreDataTableViewController to manange the different fetchedResults?

Comment: Good question. What you have to do is create subclasses of CoreDataViewController to do that because it will save you a lot of time.

Comment: You mean, every class that is going to be a TableView have to be. exampleTableView:CoreDataTableViewController, example2TableView:CoreDatTable......???

Comment: Yes one class for every table view except that you reuse code a lot and only change what it is specific to the table you want to display.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CoreData to cache data from JSON, you might want to look at https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit. It will take care of mapping between JSON objects and CodeData objects - potentially saving you a lot of code.

The model you show is not very large; examples in books and courses are deliberately small because they are only intended to teach.  Real-world databases are always larger.